# How to sing Karnei Farah and Yerach Ben Yomo

Tags: trop-cantillation

Hi I'm looking for different traditions (and sources!) about how to properly sing these very rare trop found in the Torah exclusively in Bamidbar 35:5 Does anyone have any idea which version is better / closer to the original?

Comment: I know both of them for Megillat Esther, sometimes they're pretty similar to the Torah's. Would that help you?

Comment: This is a good question, but how do you know what melody trop originally had?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman I don't! Hence my very first Mi Yodeya question. How someone could know? I don't know for sure, but age of the source involved, possible recorded testimony, or connection to the shape of the trop might be indicators.

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40241&st=&pgnum=179 for neviim

Answer (score 4):

This is the ways Sefer Hanigunnim (Chabad) says it is supposed to sound:

Trop for normal laining: http://www.770live.com/En770/nigunim/nigunPlay.asp?nigunId=Dovid_Hurwitz/172.rm&gif=172

Trop for Megillas Ester: http://www.770live.com/En770/nigunim/nigunPlay.asp?nigunId=Dovid_Hurwitz/175.rm&gif=175

Comment: Though the person singing says that he doesn't bring any alternatives to the way Sefer Hanigunim plays it because there is no way to know which nusach is the right one without Ruach Hakodesh ;)

Answer (score 4):

Karnei Farah - according to Minhag Askhenaz - is Pazer, Telisha Ketana and Telisha Gedolah together (meaning one after another).  I don't have the source for that though - I heard it from a local Rav and then from a Ba'al Koreh.

As for Yerach Ben Yomo, I try to imitate the guy at http://bible.ort.org/books/cant4.asp since my teacher never taught me that one.

http://taamim.org/ has the Sephardic Ta'amim.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding Ashkenazi traditions, I have compiled below the chants recorded by three early Christian humanist sources from the sixteenth century and by numerous Ashkenazi informants from around Europe.

These were brought together analyzed by Avenary in his book "The Ashkenazi Tradition of Biblical Chant between 1500 and 1900".

[image: Ashkenazi chant]

Answer (score 3):

[Here's wikimedia's version](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Mas%27e-5_hi_%28Asael%29.ogg). Listen from about 41 seconds.

Is it just me, or does it remind you of the 1812 Overture? "Alpayim Ba'amah ... <**CANNON BOOM!!**>"

Comment: Yes.  And there's another version on the web - I can't seem to find it anymore - that sounded like church singing.

Answer (score 2):

Ish Masliah Tikun Korim (these Halachot were written by HaRosh Yeshiva HaRav Meir Mazuz Shalit"a): Karne Para sounds like Pazer Gadol. Yareh Ben Yomo sounds like Shofar Holech.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you should be aware of is that a yerach Ben Yomo is a 'meshares' (was also taught that it's a long or embelished Munach - as mentioned)  A Karnei Farah is a 'mafsik' & is mentioned in minchas shai & several other places as 'Pazer Gadol'  - which could mean a big or long Pazer. (I was taught Pazer with Tlisha Gedolah) Regardless of how you sing it, a Karnei Farah needs to end with a mafsik, (it certainly should not end with a Tlisha Kitana-which is a meshares)