# Pronunciation of Tere ta’ame

Tags: trop-cantillation

The Tere ta’ame (also known as a [Merekha kefula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercha_kefula)) trope is rare, occurring only 5 times in the Torah: Genesis 27:25, Exodus 5:15, Leviticus 10:1, Numbers 14:3 and 32:42

Any sources for a recording of the Tere ta’ame trope?

**Added** Yes, I was referring to the Merekha kefula trope in Bamidbar 14:3. Thank you for the information and answers.

Comment: _T're taame_ usually refers to the existence of two cantillations on one word, whatever they may be. Sometimes a _munach_ and a _mercha_, sometimes (IIRC) a _t'lisha_ and a _gershayim_, maybe others too. Could you clarify which one you're seeking a recording of?

Comment: @msh210, the only thing like that in parshat shalach (that I am aware of) is a mercha kfula, and that is a single trup (as far as I am aware in the Ashkenazi and Syrian traditions) with a sound distinct to that of two merchas.

Comment: related-ish: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9108/759

Comment: @msh210 I've also heard mercha kefula called trei taamei, see for eg http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A5:TAMI_MIKRA_MIZRAH.png

Comment: I have a theory that it's just a regular Merkha, and the second note is to emphasize that it's conjuctive, unlike the expected disjunctive Tevir between Darga and Tipcha. The second conjunctive back from Tipcha is Darga, but since it's rare you can confuse the Merkha for a Tipcha. (Notably it's always on a short word which could explain the lack of disjunctive.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're calling it "*trei taamei*", you are likely Sephardic, in which case, you can probably find a recording of the taamim (including *tre taamei*) according to your specific custom at [Pizmonim.org](http://www.pizmonim.com/taamim.php).

For the standard Ashkenazic custom, the tune given in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7y6evS-Arg#t=67s) (at 1:07) is the one I and many others I know use. (I wouldn't necessarily trust that video for all of the other *taamim*, though.)

Answer (score 4):

The Trope Trainer software (published by Kinnor, sometimes discounted at Davka) includes computer-generated recordings of everything in a couple dozen different cantillation systems.  You can sometimes find recordings of passages on the net but unless the recording uses the system you're familiar with, this doesn't necessarily help.

Some tikkunim include musical notation, so if the one you use represents your community's trope system, another approach would be to ask someone who reads music to help out.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.beverlyhillschabad.com/torah-reading/BAMIDBAR/168Shelach.htm) is a recording of R' Shusterman (who used to read the Torah in 770) reading Parshas Shelach.

Comment: The relevant pasuk (Numbers 14:3) is at right about 6:00 into the recording if you download the full parshas Sh'lach audio.