# unsual haftarah trope in bechalotecha/hannukkah

Tags: trop-cantillation, haftarah

In the haftarah for Behaalotecha/Hanukkah 1 there is an unusual [trope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantillation) for the word *zeh* in [Zekhariah 3:2](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2303.htm#2):

> וַיֹּ֨אמֶר יְהוָ֜ה אֶל־הַשָּׂטָ֗ן יִגְעַ֨ר יְהוָ֤ה בְּךָ֙ הַשָּׂטָ֔ן וְיִגְעַ֤ר יְהוָה֙ בְּךָ֔ הַבֹּחֵ֖ר בִּירֽוּשָׁלִָ֑ם הֲל֧וֹא **זֶ֦ה** א֖וּד מֻצָּ֥ל מֵאֵֽשׁ׃
>
> And the *Hashem* said unto Satan: 'The *Hashem* rebuke thee, O Satan, yea, the *Hashem* that hath chosen Jerusalem rebuke thee; is not **this** man a brand plucked out of the fire?'

It looks like two commas next to each other. I have asked the teacher at my *shul* and have listened to some online chantings of the haftarah, and they just make it a [tevir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tevir), but it's not. I found one online site calling it a *mercha kefula* but the attached audio is for its chanting in a Torah reading, not haftarah.  Does anyone know how to chant it for haftarah?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16802/759

Comment: Are you looking specifically for online audios? If not, I think "Trope Trainer" has all the trope notes in each of the modes (Torah, Nevi'im, Ketuvim, Esther, Eicha, etc.) From what I recall, it sounds like two *tevirs* one after the other. That somewhat makes sense as this note always follows a darga, and darga is typically followed by *tvir*.

Answer (score 4):

Adapting and extending a comment by DoubleAA:

It's called, by different communities, "[mercha kefula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercha_kefula)" or "trei taamei". You can hear it chanted, in the Haftara context you found it in, by Yeshiva University's [R' Dr. Jeremy Wieder](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremy_Wieder) [here](https://www.yutorah.org/search/?s=wieder+haftarah+Beha%60alotecha&sort=1), by Chabad's R' Michoel Slavin [here][4], or by the Sephardic Pizmonim Project's [Meyer Kairey](http://www.pizmonim.org/hazzan.php?hazzan=MKairey) [here](http://www.pizmonim.org/book.php?recording=3386#P523).