# Seeking online audio for "Mas'ei trope"

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, torah-reading, masei

IY"H, I shall be reading parshiot *Matot / Mas'ei* this coming Shabbat.

I am looking for an online audio version to practice these two areas both in Mas'ei:

- Years ago, I heard someone lain a special trope for the *masa'ot* - the section enumerating the places B'nai Israe'l travelled, as described in B'midbar 33:10-49. I haven't been able to locate this special trope.
- The *yerach ben yomo / karnei parah* combo in B'midbar 35:5

I used to use Trope Trainer. But, since I upgraded my PC, recently, the old Windows 32 bit version won't work (I have Windows 7 - unless someone can suggest a work-around.)

Comment: You could try running 32-bit Windows in a virtual machine on your Windows 7 PC if you still have the product key

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9108/759

Comment: I run Trope Trainer on my Mac using CrossOver (poor man's virtualization, sort of), so Daniel's suggestion is highly likely to work.

Answer (score 8):

[YUTorah.org](http://www.yutorah.org/) has free, streaming Torah reading recordings by [R' Jeremy Weider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremy_Wieder). He enunciates and intones extremely clearly. He performs the two features you're looking for:

- The *masa'ot* start at 06:00 in his [Laining for Matot Mas`ei Part 4](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/707892/Rabbi_Jeremy_Wieder/Laining_for_Matot_Mas%60ei_Part_4).
- 35:5, with the unusual *trop*, starts at 02:07 in his [Laining for Matot Mas`ei Part 6](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/707894/Rabbi_Jeremy_Wieder/Laining_for_Matot_Mas%60ei_Part_6).

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to run the program using XP mode.
Instructions may be found here
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7

Comment: Hello, welcome to Mi Yodeya. Thank you for sharing your knowledge with us. Consider taking the following short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about the site. Hope to see you around.

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Navigating the Bible II by ORT](http://bible.ort.org/intro1.asp?lang=1). They have all of the leining for Torah and Haftarah, read by [Cantor Moshe Haschel](http://bible.ort.org/books/help.asp?action=displaytext&type=1&id=3), both as entire parshiot and pasuk by pasuk, all free. Their Masei recording includes both features you're looking for.

- I only listened to [33:10](http://bible.ort.org/books/torahd5.asp?action=displaypage&book=4&chapter=33&verse=9&portion=43) and 11, but it seems to use the special trop.
- [35:5](http://bible.ort.org/books/torahd5.asp?action=displaypage&book=4&chapter=35&verse=5&portion=43), including the *yerach ben yomo* and *karnei farah*.

You'll need to use either RealPlayer or [VLC Media Player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) to listen to it, AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about the ORT program. I haven't used that in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you are looking for OP, but for any yemenites who stumble upon this thread, this is what I use.

www.moryapp.co.il